# No se admiten varios conjuntos de objetos por tipo error al usar EF luego de adicionar una tabla a Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model, identity

Le adicioné una tabla a Identity: Solicitud, lo probé y funcionaba bien. Luego creé un controlador con vistas de modo automático usando EF y ahora sale el mensaje de error:

No se admiten varios conjuntos de objetos por tipo. Los conjuntos de objetos 'ApplicationUsers' y 'Users' pueden contener instancias de tipo 'PruebaHG.Models.ApplicationUser'.
Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código.

Detalles de la excepción: System.InvalidOperationException: No se admiten varios conjuntos de objetos por tipo. Los conjuntos de objetos 'ApplicationUsers' y 'Users' pueden contener instancias de tipo 'PruebaHG.Models.ApplicationUser'.

Error de código fuente:

Se ha generado una excepción no controlada durante la ejecución de la solicitud Web actual. La información sobre el origen y la ubicación de la excepción pueden identificarse utilizando la excepción del seguimiento de la pila siguiente.

Seguimiento de la pila:

```
[InvalidOperationException: No se admiten varios conjuntos de objetos por tipo. Los conjuntos de objetos 'ApplicationUsers' y 'Users' pueden contener instancias de tipo 'PruebaHG.Models.ApplicationUser'.]
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.DbSetDiscoveryService.RegisterSets(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) +456
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModelBuilder() +360
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext) +128
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input) +123
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +616
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() +21
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +15
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +16
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.FindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Object[] keyValues) +53
   System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.FindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Object[] keyValues) +35
   System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.FindAsync(Object[] keyValues) +26
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.EntityStore`1.GetByIdAsync(Object id) +49
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.<GetUserAggregateAsync>d__67.MoveNext() +136
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult() +59
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.<<OnValidateIdentity>b__0>d.MoveNext() +789
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) +25
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.<AuthenticateCoreAsync>d__2.MoveNext() +2200
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<BaseInitializeAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +571
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +255
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext() +383
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext() +383
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext() +383
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext() +182
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<DoFinalWork>d__2.MoveNext() +180
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar) +69
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar) +64
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +380
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +48
```

He buscado por ahí, pero no puedo ver algo duplicado.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Tenga en cuenta que el valor de authenticationType debe coincidir con el definido en CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Agregar aquí notificaciones personalizadas de usuario
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public virtual List<Solicitud> Solicitudes { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Solicitud>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.Usuario)
            .WithMany(x => x.Solicitudes)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.Id)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<PruebaHG.Models.Solicitud> Solicituds { get; set; }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<PruebaHG.Models.ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }

}
```

La clase Solicitud

```
public class Solicitud
    {
        [Key]
        public int IdSolicitud { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaYHora { get; set; }
        public String Tipo { get; set; }
        public bool AprobadoPorRH { get; set; }
        public bool AprobadoPorJefe { get; set; }

        public String Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser Usuario { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: No se si es la causa pero esta linea no debería estar ya que identity agrega esa tabla por si misma.`public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<PruebaHG.Models.ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }`

Comment: Sí,. eso era... al parecer por lo que leí, es mejor no usar scafolding. Gracias @denifer

Comment: Gracias @denifersantiagofernandez, en mi caso esa linea se agregó al utilizar scafolding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este error me ocurrió después de utilizar el `scaffolding` con la entidad `ApplicationUser`, esto debido a que se agregó la siguiente linea al `DbContext` mientras que `IdentityDbContext` ya la implementa:

```cs
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<PruebaHG.Models.ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
```

Para solucionar el error se debe de eliminar la linea agregada automaticamente por el scaffold

Creditos:
[denifer santiago fernandez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/95875/denifer-santiago-fernandez)

Comment: Buen trabajo conviertiendolo en respuesta